# Eclipse application not loading required bundle

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP-based application that has a dependency on a bundle that requires `sun.misc`.  At start time, it is not resolved because it can't find the package:

```
id  State       Bundle
150 INSTALLED   org.diirt.support.diirt-pva_3.1.6.20170118092719
osgi> start 150
gogo: BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.diirt.support.diirt-pva [150]
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.epics.pvaccess; version="[4.1.0,5.0.0)"
    -> Export-Package: org.epics.pvaccess; bundle-symbolic-name="org.epics.pvAccessJava"; bundle-version="4.1.3"; version="4.1.3"; uses:="org.epics.pvdata.pv"
       org.epics.pvAccessJava [307]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: sun.misc
```

Meanwhile **in the built product's plugins directory** is `com.diffplug.osgi.extension.sun.misc_0.0.0.jar`.  This provides the package `sun.misc`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: sun.misc
Fragment-Host: system.bundle; extension:=framework
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-License: public domain - http://unlicense.org/
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.diffplug.osgi.extension.sun.misc
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0
```

However, this is not loaded when the application starts:

```
osgi> ss diff
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
```

Why is this required bundle not loaded?

Incidentally, this plugin is required in a feature that is included in the product.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, sun.misc should be resolvable in com.diffplug.osgi:com.diffplug.osgi.extension.sun.misc:0.0.0 
Perhaps you could try adding this to your project?

Comment: Well, that's the idea.  It's just that after we've built the product (and the plugin is there) it's not getting loaded when we start up, and I don't know why.